# How to handle display of data from database using a condition in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named account.

Table: **account**

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| user_id | email               | u_name    |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
|      63 | Vicman@gmai.com     | Pross     |
|      64 | Pink@gmai.com       | Pross     |
|      73 | Victor@gmail.com    | Victorss  |
|      74 | ifeco_man@yahoo.com | Ifecosss  |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
```

But I want to change all the display u_name into "**No**" from my table whose u_name = "Pross" in my page like this:

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| user_id | email               | u_name    |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
|      63 | Vicman@gmai.com     | No        |
|      64 | Pink@gmai.com       | No        |
|      73 | Victor@gmail.com    | Victorss  |
|      74 | ifeco_man@yahoo.com | Ifecosss  |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
```

But my code here replaces all the rows with "No". Seems like the placement of my condition is wrong. Here's my code in
php to fetch data from database.

```
<!--############# TABLE CONTENT ##############-->
<tbody>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($s1)) {
    # Columns from DB
    $db_id = $row['user_id'];
    $db_email = $row['email'];
    $db_uname = $row['u_name']; 

    # Condition to handle display of u_name row
    if($db_uname == "Pross") {
        $db_uname_edit = "No";
    }
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $db_id ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db_email ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db_uname_edit ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</tbody>
<!--##########################################-->
```

But the unwanted output of this is :

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| user_id | email               | u_name    |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
|      63 | Vicman@gmai.com     | No        |
|      64 | Pink@gmai.com       | No        |
|      73 | Victor@gmail.com    | No        |
|      74 | ifeco_man@yahoo.com | No        |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Why ? Can anybody help me with my code above ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should set the value of $db_uname_edit to $db_uname in else part:

```
if($db_uname == "Pross") {
    $db_uname_edit = "No";
} else {
    $db_uname_edit = $db_uname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Condition to handle display of u_name row
if($db_uname == "Pross") {
    $db_uname_edit = "No";
}
else {
    $db_uname_edit = $db_uname;
}
```

This should work.

And here is the shortened edition, you won't need an `if` clause:

```
<td><?php echo $db_uname == 'Pross' ? 'No' : $db_uname ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your "if" statement to:

```
 if($db_uname === "Pross") {
        $db_uname_edit = "No";
    }
```

when compareing strings you should use the "===" operator instead of "=="

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `else` part in `if` condition if condition not matched then code goto else condition

```
if($db_uname == "Pross") {
    $db_uname_edit = "No";
} else {
    $db_uname_edit = $db_uname;
}
```

OR better user `ternary` operator to reduce code

```
$db_uname_edit = $db_uname == "Pross" ? "No" : $db_uname;
```

And You can do this in `DB` query, that would be good for performance

```
select user_id, email, IF(u_name = 'Pross', 'No', u_name) AS u_name FROM account
```